# how to stop media player running inside a thread

Tags: android

I am trying to stop a media player and get out  of my activity class whenever the stop option of the process dialog is pressed,but by using the below code i am able to getting out of my activity class but unable to stop the media player sound ,and it is running continuously  till the thread stop..

Please help me on this matter 
Thanx in advance..

```
public class Test_Service extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mp;
private Thread welcomeThread;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Test_Service.this,R.raw.alarm1);


    welcomeThread=new Thread() {
      int wait = 0;
            @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                super.run();
                    while (wait <30000) {

                     mp.start();
                     sleep(3000);
                    wait +=3000;
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("EXc=" + e);
            } finally {

        }
        }
    };
    new AlertDialog.Builder(Test_Service.this)
    .setTitle("Alarm is running")
    .setPositiveButton("Stop",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        mp.stop();
                    welcomeThread.stop(); 
        Test_Service.this.finish();

    }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        mp.stop();
        Test_Service.this.finish();


}
    })
    .create().show();
    welcomeThread.start();
        }

    }
```

Comment: welcomeThread.stop(); is not a good practice instead use welcomeThread.interrupt();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use a `Handler` with it's [`postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) method to delay the start.

Furthermore you can set the following `OnDismissListener` on your AlertDialog and stop the player there to avoid code repetition.

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        mp.release();
        handler.removeCallbacks(startingRunnable);
        finish();
    }
});
```

[`MediaPlayer.release()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release%28%29) will stop your MediaPlayer and release it. If you want to reuse this MediaPlayer you will have to create a new one after calling `release()`.